# How to store openssl_public_encrypt() output in MySQL database?

Tags: php, mysql, openssl

I have a need to store an encrypted but recoverable (by admin) password in MySQL, from PHP.  AFAIK, the most straightforward way to do this is with openssl_public_encrypt(), but I'm not sure what column type is needed.  Can I make any reliable judgment on the maximum length of encrypted output, based upon the size of the key and the input?

Or am I forced to use a huge field (e.g. BLOB), and just hope it works all the time?

Comment: Storing passwords in reversable encryption is a bad idea.  You should use a salted hash instead.

Comment: It is a requirement and the premise of my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `openssl_public_encrypt` function limits the size of the data you can encrypt to the length of the key, if you use padding (recommended), you'll lose an extra 11 bytes.

> However, the PKCS#1 standard, which OpenSSL uses, specifies a padding scheme (so you can encrypt smaller quantities without losing security), and that padding scheme takes a minimum of 11 bytes (it will be longer if the value you're encrypting is smaller). So the highest number of bits you can encrypt with a 1024-bit key is 936 bits because of this (unless you disable the padding by adding the OPENSSL_NO_PADDING flag, in which case you can go up to 1023-1024 bits). With a 2048-bit key it's 1960 bits instead.

Of course you should **never** disable padding, because that will make the same passwords to encrypt to the same value.

So for a 1024-bit key the maximum password input length is 117 chars.
For a 2048-bit key it's 245 chars.

I'm not 100% sure of the output length, but a simple trail should confirm this, the output is a simple function of the keylength, so for a 2048-bit key I suspect it is 256 bytes.

You should use a `binary` string with the required length to store the password.
For speed reasons it's best to use a limited length index on the field.
Do not use blob (!) because that will slow things way down for no benefit.

```
CREATE TABLE user
  id unsigned integer auto_increment primary key,
  username varchar(50) not null,
  passRSA binary(256),      <<-- doublecheck the length.
  index ipass(passRSA(10))  <<-- only indexes the first 10 bytes for speed reasons. 
) ENGINE = InnoDB
```

Adding extra bytes to the index will just slow things down and grow the index file for no benefit.

Comment: Do you have any documentation reference that states output is strictly a function of key length?  I can always run tests, but that would not prove my design outside of the test cases.

Comment: @CakeLad, it's a logical consequence of the algorithm.